# AngularJS: Send $http.get requests continuously until certain condition

Tags: angularjs, callback, get

As the title says, I want to send $http.get requests to the server until the returned results meets a condition.

This is what I tried:

```
    var searchComplete = false;
    var sendGetReq = true;

    while(!searchComplete) // #2 and then jumps here
    {
       if(sendGetReq)
       {
         sendGetReq = false;  // #1 execution reaches here
         $http.get('/user/getCondition', {params: {condition: $scope.condition}).
        success(function (condition, status, headers, config) {
         ...
         ...
         if(condition)
         { searchComplete = true; }
         else
         { sendGetReq = true; }
    }
}
```

However, the $http.get request never goes. That statement is never reached. When I debugged, I saw that execution will come to `sendGetReq=false` and then jump to `while(!searchComplete)`. The GET request is never sent.

Would someone please explain:

1. Why the execution never reaches GET request and jumps back
2. What is the recommended way to to do this continuous GET request

Thank you.

Comment: Use ```.then```, not ```.success```, and you should make this a recursive function. Don't expect perfect behavior using a while and a promise together. Make youself a function that calls itself once the promise has returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not put it all together inside a function and call itself if condition is meet? Like this and you should use .then and not .success:

```
$scope.load = function(){
  $http.get('/user/getCondition', {params: {condition: $scope.condition}).
    then(function (condition, status, headers, config) {

    if (condition){
       $scope.load();
    }

  });
}
```

Hope it helps =)

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `while (true)`, especially in JS.

JS works in one thread. `$http.get` will never run because your main thread stalled in you infinite loop and do not gave a chance for other threads to run.

**Update**

```
function getHttpPromise() {
    return $http.get('/user/getCondition', {params: {condition: $scope.condition}).
        success(function (condition, status, headers, config) {
         ...
         ...
         if(condition)
             return true;//or any result you want to resolve
         else
             return getHttpPromise();
    }
}
```

`getHttpPromise` function returns promise, which will be resolved on your `condition`, in other case it will continues waiting with followed get request.

To use it, run the following code.

```
getHttpPromise().then(function (result) {
    // Will be called only when condition will be successful
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`$http.get` is asynchronous call and it will hit the success or error (both are deprecated, use then) function on response from server. When the function reaches this line

```
sendGetReq = false;  // #1 execution reaches here
```

it makes the `$http.get` call (which is async) and then it moves the control to next iteration. That is the main purpose of async call.

If you want to make continuous calls you can write the `$http.get` call in a function and call that function using `interval` service of Angular JS.

[$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval)

```
$scope.func = function(){
   if(condition)
   {
      $http.get....
   }      
}

$interval($scope.func, 1000)
```

where 1000 is the time interval in milliseconds after which the function is called

Comment: with `$timeout` you call the function just one time. Maybe you need `$interval` but anyway is not a good solution. You should use the then (success) for call recursively your function

Comment: @gianlucatursi Edited my answer for $interval

Answer (score 1):

Try this inject `$interval` in your controller

```
var startInterval = $interval(function(){
  var searchComplete = false;
  var sendGetReq = true;

        sendGetReq = false;  // #1 execution reaches here
        $http.get('/user/getCondition', {params: {condition: $scope.condition}).
        success(function (condition, status, headers, config) {
         if(condition)
         {   searchComplete = true;
            $scope.stopInterval();
         }
         else
         { sendGetReq = true; }
        })

},1000)

$scope.stopInterval = function(){
   $interval.cancel(startInterval)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Andrew said it should be recursive and in your case use .then. To make it recursive encapsulate your $http service inside a function

```
.controller('YourController', function($http) {
this.sendGetReq= function(data) {
    $http.get('/user/getCondition', {params: {condition: data.condition}).
    .then(function(res) {
        if (res.condition) {
        //finish your search
        } else {
        //set newdata somehow   
          this.sendGetReq(newdata);
        }
    }
};
```

});