# Sending multiple GET requests with changing parameter in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Edit**: Apologies to the answerers, it turns out that this was actually valid code, but requests were being intercepted and stripped of all of the parameters.

---

I'm trying to make repeated HTTP GET requests to a REST API, depending on the output and have used the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39230788/angularjs-send-http-get-requests-continuously-until-certain-condition).

However, I wish to increment one of the parameters that I pass in the request. Essentially, the API pages the output and I need to increase the value of `startAt` accordingly.

Manual requests work fine with:

```
<URL>/board?startAt=50
```

And give back:

```
{"maxResults":50,"startAt":50,"isLast":true,"values":[list_of_values]}
```

Here's my code so far:

```js
function getHttpPromise(start_at) {
    // This function recurses until the server returns isLast = true.
    //
    // Each iteration appends the values in response.values to
    // $scope.boards.
    test = $http({
                    url: 'boards',
                    method: 'GET',
                    params: {'startAt': start_at.toString()}
                 }).
        success(function (response) {
            console.log(response); // the response contains startAt, which always has 
                                   // the initial value (0), rather than start_at's value

            var values = response.values;
            for (var i in values) {
                var board = values[i];
                $scope.boards[board.id] = board;
            }

            if (response.isLast) {
                // We have received all the boards.
                return true;
            } else {
                // Increment start_at and return another http request promise.
                start_at += response.maxResults;
                return getHttpPromise(start_at);
            }
        }
    );

    console.log(test); // params is correct here

    return test;
}
```

This function is called by:

```
jiraWorkLog.controller('SprintSelectCtlr',
function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    $scope.init = function() {
        $scope.boards = new Object();

        getHttpPromise(0).then(
            function (dummy_var) {
            for (var board in $scope.boards) {
                ...
            }
        }
    );
}
...
);
```

Comment: what do you see in the console when you do `console.log(response.maxResults);`  before adding it to `start_at`?   
What do you see in the when you do `console.log(start_at);` before and after the value is incremented?

Comment: where  are you calling this **getHttpPromise** ??

Comment: @Fran the value is being incremented correctly (`response.maxResults=50` and `start_at=0 => start_at=50` etc.).

@Aravind I edited my question accordingly. It's in our `SprintCtlr` object.

Comment: So are you suggesting that you solved your issue or that you no longer think your question is valid?  It's not really clear what your latest update is trying to say.  If this isn't a valid question any longer, then you should delete it.  If you solved the issue and you think the solution would be useful to others, you should provide an answer.  Self answers are valid (and encouraged).

Comment: @Claies I flagged it for a moderator, since I thought they'd have a better idea than me of what the most appropriate solution was.

Answer (score 0):

The `$http().success()` is deprecated. You should use `$http().then()`.

The `then` receives a function than will be passed a `response` object that has a property called `data`. There you'll find your `values`.

You can read further [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/http)

After reading your code more thoroughly, I must advise you not to solve this problem recursively. If you don't want the data paged, send a request for all the records upfront.

Now to answer why you only get the first result: it's because that's the only thing that is returned and the calling controller. You are returning a promise that the controller is waiting to be resolved. All other recursive calls happen only after your controller is already done.

Comment: The problem is that my request isn't being sent correctly, not getting access to the values. The request is constantly being sent with `startAt=0`

Comment: Now that you added the controller, I saw you are calling it with a hard-coded 0, that's why the request is always sent with 0

Comment: Running it in Chrome developer view, the value of `start_at` is increasing in each subsequent call (by the right amount). The 0 should just be the initial value in the first call, I thought.

Comment: Going over your question again I see plenty things wrong. I think it's a really bad practice to call REST recursively. I'm editing the answer to help you understand why you only get the first result

Comment: The recursive solution was from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39230788/angularjs-send-http-get-requests-continuously-until-certain-condition

The problem with the REST API is that there is no way of knowing how many pages there are a priori. You only know that you are finished when the response contains `isLast = true`.

Comment: Someone answering it doesn't make it good practice. I find it really hard to believe that a service that provides pagination doesn't provide fetching all the data. There's a better alternative, you just need to think harder :-)

Comment: It's this API: https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-software/REST/cloud/#agile/1.0/board-getAllBoards

I haven't found a suitable way to retrieve the total number of boards or number of pages ahead of time, as this API doesn't actually return the `total` field.

Comment: You can use `total` and set this number as `maxResults`. That's just one idea, but I think you're over thinking about it. Just use paging on your UI. There's nothing a user can do with more that 50-100 results at a time. If it's a chart or something you should call different APIs to group results

Comment: The issue is that `total` isn't returned and `maxResults` has a hardcoded maximum set by the server (over which I don't have control). On the second point, I'm not providing the user with all of the results, but populating a widget which allows the user to lookup their board without having to know the exact name or ID.

Answer (score 0):

the response holds all the http stuff and you want to get the data out of it...

I think that the following link might help you [Angular Http](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp)

another issue that you have with your recursion is that you're updating a local variable and use it wrongly...

```
function getHttpPromise(start_at) {
// This function recurses until the server returns isLast = true.
//
// Each iteration appends the values in response.values to
// $scope.boards.
test = $http({
                url: 'boards',
                method: 'GET',
                params: {'startAt': start_at.toString()}
             }).
    success(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data); // the response contains startAt, which always has 
                               // the initial value (0), rather than start_at's value

        var values = response.data;
        for (var i in values) {
            var board = values[i];
            $scope.boards[board.id] = board;
        }

        if (response.data.isLast) {
            // We have received all the boards.
            return true;
        } else {
            // Increment start_at and return another http request promise.
            return getHttpPromise(response.data.maxResults+1);
        }
    }
);

console.log(test); // params is correct here

return test;
```

}

Comment: As I said below, the problem is formulating the request, not parsing the response. The response is valid (and correct), but the request I'm sending isn't using the correct `startAt=<value>` I want.

Comment: try to update your recursion call to be getHttpPromise(response.data.maxResults+1);

Comment: `response.data.maxResults + 1` is always the same though (51). The value `start_at` is being incremented correctly, it's just not being used in the GET request.